# Why am I not able to return the index of the array in the output?

Tags: java, arrays

I am not able to return the index of the elements as an output

```
// Using Two pointers Approach
class Solution {
    public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target){
// Initilizing the index i and j
        int i = 0, j = nums.length-1;

// Using while loop
        while (i<j){
            if((nums[i] + nums[j] > target)){
            j--;

            }else if((nums[i] + nums[j] < target)){
            i++;

            }else{
 // Trying to return the index of the elements but getting elements in the output
            return new int[] {nums[i], nums[j]};
            }    
        } // while loop ends here
        return new int[] {};
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Did you mean `return new int[] {i, j};` ?

Comment: Try to return new int[] {i, j};

Comment: Do you get an error or a wrong result? If you get a wrong result please add input values, expected and actual output to you question.

Comment: @Pankaj it worked with int[] {i, j}; but not passing the other test case that is [3,2,4] and the target is 6.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `i` and `j` are the index numbers of that array, so you must have seen the output as empty array just because in your other test case the while loop ends when `i = 1 and j = 1` and the condition for the loop is `i < j` so the next loop won't happen. So to return the values of index which is `{1, 1}` according to yor other test case you have to return the `new int [] {i , j};` after the end of while loop. It's not necessary to add a return statement inside the while loop.